# Use Riemann integral to prove f is integrable on [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $S = {S_1, S_2, ....., S_k}$ be a finite subset of [a,b]. Suppose that f is a bounded function on [a,b] such that f(x) = 0 if x $\notin$ S. Show that f is integrable and that $\int_a^b$f = 0.

My attempt of this question is as follow:

Without loss of generality, suppose $f(S_i) >0$, and $f(S_i)$ is finite since f is bounded on [a,b]

Firstly, suppose $P = {x_0,x_2,.....,x_k}$ is a partition of [a,b] such that every interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ where 1$\leq$i$\leq$k, contains one $S_i$.

So in every [x_{i-1},x_i], except for the point Si, all values of f are zero. This is clear that the lower sum L(f,P) = 0 and hence the lower integral $\int_{-a}^{b}$f = sup(L(f,P)) = 0.

On the other hand, the upper sum U(f,P) = $\sum_{1}^{k}$M_i$\Delta$x_i>0 since every $M_i$ = sup(f(x), x$\in$[x_{i-1},x_i])  = f(S_i)>0 and $\Delta$x_i = x_i-x_{i-1} = (b-a)/k >0.

So the upper integral $\int_{a}^{-b}$f = inf(U(f,P))= 0, since U(f,P) >0.

Therefore, $\int_{a}^{-b}$f = $\int_{-a}^{b}$f
, hence f is integrable on [a,b] and $\int_{a}^{b}$f = 0.

The other case when $f(s_i)$ <0, the method is similar. When $f(s_i) <0$ , $f(s_i)$ will be used to calculate the lower sum U(f,P).

Could anyone please check whether the way I deduce the upper integral $\int_{a}^{-b}$f is correct? I can only conclude that the upper sum U(f,P) >0 , I cannot give a precise estimation. I am not sure about the upper sum U(f,P). Could anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: This is not clear as a general argument. It needs to be set up so one knows where the points $S_i$ lie with respect to the partition looked at. And it can't really be assumed WLOG that either all $f(S_i)>0$ or the opposite. Thee may be varying signs.

Comment: You need to use the fact that $f$ is bounded and find a specific partition $P$ so that $U(f,P) < \epsilon$. It is not hard to imagine the partition. Just contain each $S_k$ in some very small interval.

Comment: The hardest part of proving things about Riemann integrals is getting the notation on the partition constructions clear. If you're even a little sloppy,it's easy to get lost.The key needed idea here is that you have to be able to prove that there exists $\epsilon $ > 0 such that |U(f,P) - L(f,p)| < $\epsilon$.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your comments. I understand. Is it possible to prove this question using the theorem "when the upper interval is equal to the lower interval", the function f will be integrable on [a,b]?

Comment: Happy Monkey: What is the "upper interval" (and lower) you refer to in the last comment? Are you meaning upper/lower ingegrals?

Comment: @coffeemath I assume he means either the upper/lower Darboux or the upper/lower Riemann integrals-which of course,are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof inspired by an example in Micheal Spivak's *Calculus*:

Theorem: Let $S = {S_1, S_2, ....., S_k}$ be a finite subset of [a,b]. Suppose that f

is a bounded function on [a,b] such that f(x) = 0 if x $\notin$ S. Then f is integrable

and that $\int_a^b$f = 0.

Proof: Define f as follows:

$$ (1) f(x):=\cases{d\neq 0\quad& \text{if $x$ is equal to }S_i\cr 0&\text{if $x$ is not equal to }S_i\cr}\ $$

Now suppose P= ${[t_0, t_1, ..,t_j,..., t_n]}$ is a partition of [a,b] where 0$\leq j \leq n$ where $t_{j-1} < f(S_i)= d < t_j$.So WLOG,we can assume $t_j = S_i$ if i=j. Recall

$$(2) M_i = sup{f(x), x\in[t_{j-1},t_j]}$$ 
  $$(3) m_i = inf{f(x), x\in[t_{j-1},t_j]}$$

But by the above definition of f and the partition P:

$$(4) m_i=M_i=0 if i\neq j$$

$$(5) m_j=0 and M_j =d if i=j$$

So now: 
(6) $U(f,P)$ = $\sum_{1}^{j-1}M_i([t_i-t_{i-1}])$+$M_i([t_j-t_{j-1}])$ +

$\sum_{k=j+1}^{n}$M_i$\$([t_i-t_{i-1}]) $

(7) $L(f,P)$ = $\sum_{1}^{j-1} m_i([t_i-t_{i-1}])$+$m_i$\$([t_j-t_{j-1}])$ +

$\sum_{k=j+1}^{n} m_i ([t_i-t_{i-1}])$

So:
 (8) $U(f,P)-L(f,P) = d ([t_j-t_{j-1}])$.

So now it's straightforward to choose a partition P' of [a,b] where:

$$(9) U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon $$ 
 $$t_{j-1} < d < t_j$$

$$ t_j-t_{j-1} < \frac{\epsilon}{d}$$

(Why $\frac{\epsilon}{d}$ instead of $\epsilon$ for $[t_j-t_{j-1}]$ ? Think about it. )

From (2),(3),(6)- (9),it's easily deduced that:

$$ (10) L(f,P)\leq 0 \leq U(f,P) $$

By definition of the integral on [a,b],

(11) L(f,P)$\leq $ $\int_a^b$f $\leq U(f,P)$

But the number between U(f,P) and L(f,P) is unique and  therefore $\int_a^b$f = 0 and we're done! Q.E.D.

You're welcome. : )

(I didn't quite get the Jax code right again,so if someone could clean up the little bugs left in it,I'd appreciate it.)

Comment: Hi, do we have to add absolute value for d since f(Si) = d could be negative?

Comment: And I don't quite get statement (10). If statement (9) if valid for an arbitrary $\epsilon$, then f will be integrable on [a,b].

Comment: I get the meaning of statement (10) now.

Comment: We absolutely do not have to add absolute value and that's precisely because we want to allow $f(S_i) =d \leq 0$. We NEED to because in partitions, we need to allow negative values so we can take $[a,b]\subseteq R$ where a,b are not necessarily positive.